# how to send data from jquery to server side

Tags: jquery, server-side, wkhtmltopdf

sorry newbie here. I want to send the value created by jquery to server side to save to pdf using wkhtmltopdf. I got wkhtmltopdf working but blank inputs and dropdown.

**UPDATE**

sorry I'm to confused.here's what i got.

my jquery onchange

```
$("#description").change(function()
            {
            $("#page").empty();
            $("#page").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id2 = $("#description option:selected").attr('value');
                        $.post("./includes/select_producprice_n_showpage.php", {id2:id2},
                        function(data1){
                        $("#page").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $("#page").html(data1);

                        //show price---------------------------
                        $("#productPrice").html(data1);
                        });
                        });
```

select_producprice_n_showpage.php

```
<?php
include "select.class.php";
echo $opt->productPrice();
echo $opt->ShowPage();
?>
```

my php to query

```
public function productPrice()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT prodPrice FROM description WHERE id_type = $_POST[id2]";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
            $price =  $row['prodPrice'];
            return $price;
        }

        public function ShowPage()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM insidepage WHERE id_p = $_POST[id2]";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $page = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $page .= '<option value="' . $row['id_price'] . '">' . $row['insidepage'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $page;
        }
```

here's where my data will be generated by jquery

```
<td align="left">   <select id="description"></select>  </td>
<td align="center"> <label id="productPrice"></label>   </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is relative on how the server is able to accept your request.

If the server accept an HTTP Post/Get, you can try to send it using JQuery.post() or get() method, which described in detail in this link :
[jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `$.ajax()` for this. See [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) .

Might be `get` or `post`. depending on your requirements.